# How to create select for enum attribute in Rails 4 with simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, simple-form

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get my select field to work for an enum attribute using Simple_form on a Rails 4.2 app.

Here is my model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  # returns the full name of the employee. This code is found in a concern called name.rb
  include Name

  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  enum status: [:active, :vacation, :unemployed]

    enum os: [:mac, :windows]

    validates :first_name, 
            presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 2}

  validates :last_name, 
            presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 2}

    validates :email, email: true, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :paypal_email, email: true, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    # validates :status, presence: true
  validates :skype_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :mobile, presence: true, numericality: true, length: {minimum: 10}
  validates :address, :province_state, :country, :postal_code, :bachelor_degree, :os, presence: true #, , , ,, :os, presence: true

end
```

Here is my form:

```
<h2>New Employee Registration Form</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :email, required: true%>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :paypal_email, required: true%>
    <%= f.input :mobile, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :skype_id, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :address, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :province_state, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :country, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :postal_code, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :bachelor_degree, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :os, as: :select, collection: Employee.os.keys, selected: 1, required: true %>
    <%= f.input :status, as: :select, collection: Employee.status.keys, selected: 1, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Register New Employee" %>
  </div>
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

Failure/Error: <%= f.input :status, as: :select, collection: Employee.status.keys, selected: 1, required: true %>

ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `status' for #

The strange thing is that the exact same code for a similar field just 'os' works perfectly.

Appreciate any help to figure out why this attribute produces the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like that :

> f.input : os, :collection => Employee.statuses.keys.to_a

You need to use the plurialized version of status.

Comment: Thanks Supernini. Just a note, I didn't need to use the to_a and it works great.  Much appreciated.